# Searchbar doesn't show up correctly - bootstrap & rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to put a search bar with three buttons on my site. The buttons represent 3 different searches (so they will be more like toggles).

I tried this code, but the output wasn't as expected:

```
<div class="row search-row">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button></span><span class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
      <input id="file-button" src="text.png" type="image"></button></span><span class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span>
    </button></span><input class="form-control" type="text"><span class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn btn-default" type="button" value="Go"></button></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a screen shot, the top is unedited, the bottom is me trying to call attention to the issues:

[image: searchbar]

**How do I get the buttons and the text to all look like the same input (flush with no bumps)?**

Comment: Check out `input-group-addon`

Comment: Aren't those not buttons?

For the left side, I figured it out, I have too many button groups. No idea for the right side though.

Comment: Add `&nbsp;` in the button: `<button class="btn btn-default" type="button" value="Go">&nbsp;</button>`

Comment: What did you figure out for the left side? If you have a solution for that edit your question and add it in, may be useful for someone else. As for the button on the right, Dan is kind of right. If you are using a `<button>` tag you should have the value you want to appear within the two tags. Like this `<button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go</button>`. Only use `value` if you are doing it as an input, e.g. `<input type="submit" value="Go!" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code fixes it:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row search-row">
    <div class="container col-lg-6">
      <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button><button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
        <input id="file-button" src="text.png" type="image"></button><button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span>
      </button></span><input class="form-control" type="text"><span class="input-group-btn"><a class="btn btn-default go-search" href="#">Go</a></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Screenshot:

[image: fixed]

Basically, there should be one button group span for all the buttons on the left. I changed the "go" button to be a link since thats what I really need it to be anyway.